# Creating a template database

Tags: database

Is it possible to create a template database from an existing one quickly(by just copying files maybe?)

I am creating a profiling environment where the database needs to be loaded with some information to start off with. This information is static but very large. What is the fastest way to make copies of such a DB?

I am open to using any in memory database (like sqllite).

Comment: Entirely depends on the database you are using. Which is what?

Comment: I'm using MySQL currently, but am open to any suitable DB that allows me to create new instances of this large static DB quickly and efficiently. Ideally a process as efficient as a file copy.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL just create your database as always, name it e.g my_template. When creating a new database, just specify the name of your template:

```
CREATE DATABASE m_db TEMPLATE = my_template;
```

And the new one will be an exact copy (including data) of the my_template DB.

Answer (score 1):

The files for MySQL MyISAM Databases can be copied but you need to change permissions and perform some other tasks to get it working with a new name. It's usually simpler to just dump the database to a file and re-import it.

The simplest way to do this, if you don't mind the database you use, is to use something like the Java based Hypersonic database. That's really easy to copy and work with new versions.